# Why i can't fix the boxes alignment in Gridview on windows

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

there are some space between the result as you can see in the image that password entry and generate password aren't aligning together

*[Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTQzD.png)

```
from tkinter import 
window = Tk()
window.title("Password Manager")
window.config(padx=20, pady=20)
canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=200, highlightthickness=0)
password_image = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")

image = canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=password_image)
canvas.itemconfig(image)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=1)

website_label = Label(text="Website")
website_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
Email_username_label = Label(text="Email/Username")
Email_username_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
password_label = Label(text="Password")
password_label.grid(row=3, column=0)


website_input = Entry(width=35)
website_input.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2)
Email_username_input = Entry(width=35)
Email_username_input.grid(row=2,column=1, columnspan=2)
password = Entry(width=21)
password.grid(row=3, column=1)

generate_button = Button(text="Generate Password")
generate_button.grid(row=3, column=2)
add_password_button = Button(text="Add", width=36)
add_password_button.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2)



window.mainloop()
```

You can see that there is some space in password entry and generate password how to fix it

Comment: Have you read anything about the `sticky` attribute when you call `grid()`?

Comment: Try `canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)`.  Also you can set `sticky` option of `grid()` on those widgets to see the different effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, using the grid method allows you to just add `sticky` to align elements. In this case, I've removed all the `width` options in your entries and buttons with `stick='EW'` to expand East and West, or to the maximum left and right of the column the widget is in.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Password Manager")
window.config(padx=20, pady=20)


# Canvas
canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=200, highlightthickness=0)
password_image = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
image = canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=password_image)
canvas.itemconfig(image)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=1)

# Labels
website_label = Label(text="Website")
website_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
Email_username_label = Label(text="Email/Username")
Email_username_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
password_label = Label(text="Password")
password_label.grid(row=3, column=0)

# Entries
website_input = Entry()
website_input.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky='EW')  # sticky
Email_username_input = Entry()
Email_username_input.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky='EW')  # sticky
password = Entry()
password.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='EW')  # sticky

# Buttons
generate_button = Button(text="Generate Password")
generate_button.grid(row=3, column=2)
add_password_button = Button(text="Add")
add_password_button.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky='EW')  # sticky

window.mainloop()
```

You may also want to consider reading up on [column and row weights](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html) using `columnconfigure` and `rowconfigure` if you want your GUI to resize dynamically.